Accepting String and Displaying String in 8086 Assembly Programming
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    address_req1    DB  10, 13, "        Enter Shipping Address (Line 1): $"
    address_req2    DB  10, 13, "                               (Line 2): $"
    address_req3    DB  10, 13, "                               (Line 3): $"
    add_input1          DB      25, 0, 23 dup ('$')
    add_input2          DB      25, 0, 23 dup ('$')
    add_input3          DB      25, 0, 23 dup ('$')



.code
ACCEPT_STRING PROC

    mov ah, 09h             ;display request address1
    lea dx, address_req1
    int 21h
    
    mov ah, 0ah             ;accept address1
    lea dx, add_input1
    int 21h
    
    mov ah, 09h             ;display request address2
    lea dx, address_req2
    int 21h
    
    mov ah, 0ah             ;accept address2
    lea dx, add_input2
    int 21h

    mov ah, 09h             ;display request address3
    lea dx, address_req3
    int 21h
    
    mov ah, 0ah             ;accept address3
    lea dx, add_input3
    int 21h

    ret
ACCEPT_STRING ENDP

PRINT_STRING PROC

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, add_input1 + 2
    int 21h

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, add_input2 + 2
    int 21h

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, add_input3 + 2
    int 21h

    ret
PRINT_STRING ENDP



MAIN    PROC    FAR

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    call    ACCEPT_STRING
    call    PRINT_STRING

    mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h

    MAIN    ENDP
END     MAIN

The system is expected to request 3 lines of input from user one by one (in which it is successful). However, the output is incorrect (no garbage lines, just the strings are jumbled up)

Why do you prefix labels with "add_" ?

Why do you do + 2 in lea dx, add_input1 + 2 ?

@MikeNakis: +2 to get the start of the string data, skipping the buffer-size and actual-input-len bytes from the DOS read-string interface.  And I'm guessing the add_ is short for address_.  It's the input the user gave for shipping address #1.

Doesn't 25 as the max input length allow inputs that overwrite all the $ terminators (for the DOS 09h output function), leaving an unterminated string if the user inputs the max length?  Or even going beyond that, potentially overwriting the length bytes for the next input, I forget if the 25 is the whole buffer length limit including itself, or if it applies to just the part after the length bytes where you only have 23 bytes.  https://web.archive.org/web/20230322092407/http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a isn't 100% clear.

@PeterCordes The 21.0A first byte is the size of the data buffer, not including the two count bytes, up to 255. Second byte gets the actual size of data, excluding the terminating CR, so up to 254. When you set 25 as first byte you should fill the data buffer with 26 '$', not less.

Please explain what you mean by "the strings are jumbled up".  Show some sample input, and the corresponding output.

@ecm: Ok, that's what I thought.  What if the user holds down a key for more than 254 repeats without pressing enter?  Does DOS invent a CR anyway and leave the unread bytes in the input buffer, or does it discard characters past 254 other than the CR?  (Also, this is stdin so it could be coming from a file I guess, not necessarily the console.)  Not relevant to this question, but your statement that the actual-length byte couldn't be higher than 254 got me curious about corner cases.  (Sorry for cluttering up comments with this tangent.)

25, 0, 23 dup ('$') should probably be 25, 0, 26 dup ('$').  25 is how many characters you want to allow, and the buffer must be longer by 1 in order to have a trailing '$' even if it gets completely filled.

@MikeNakis the prefix add_ is bcs im labelling it as address input (just for my own convenience)

For example output wise, 1st string input: aaaaaa, 2nd string input: bbbbb; 3rd string input: cccc; the output: ccccba

In the case that the third input is longer than the past 2, it just prints the third input

Each string ends with CR so after each print code returns to the begining of the line and prints next string. First: aaaaaa + CR, output; aaaaaa. second: bbbbb + CR, output: bbbbba, third: cccc + CR, output:ccccba.

@ DylanKhor I think your problem is that you're displaying the Carriage Return (CR) that DOS appends to your input, resulting in the output being reset to the start column of the current line. @PeterCordes I think DOS (or other line editors, eg CmdEdit, DOSKey) will just discard keypresses that would insert a byte so that the input line wouldn't fit any more. May or may not involve an error indication such as displaying a BEL.

oh wait thats the problem
THANKS FOR THE HELP

Each buffer can take 25 characters, 24 + CR but buffers are only 23 long. Cool thing is that last typed in character determines max length of the next buffer.

@Nassau How exactly "last typed in character determines max length of the next buffer"? You mean if they overflow one of the input buffers so its last content bytes overwrite the beginning of the next buffer?

@ecm Yes, in case of buffer 1 and 2. If byte 24 is for example 1, byte 25 is CR so first 2 bytes of buffer 2 will change and new size will be 49 bytes.

To sum up the discussion in the comments:
(Otherwise the question will be left forever open, and future readers will have to read through tens of comments to find the answer)
When printing a string with MS-DOS interrupt 21h, function 09h, the string needs to be terminated with a dollar sign ('$').
When reading a string with MS-DOS interrupt 21h, function 0ah, the string is ended with a Carriage Return. (ASCII control character name 'CR', ASCII code 13 in decimal, 0Dh in hexadecimal.)
When the CR character is printed, it causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the current line, but not to the next line.
Therefore after printing a string that was previously read, you must print a Linefeed (ASCII control character name 'LF', ASCII code 10 in decimal, 0Ah in hexadecimal) to move to the next line, otherwise the next string you print will be printed on the same line as the previous one.

Note for future readers: this question would have been a lot more successful if the original poster had bothered to show their sample input and "garbled output" right from the start, instead of having to be coerced to do so in the comments.
